# How to prevent somebody from checking in ASP.NET code that uses a msgbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

So I have a colleague that keep using `msgbox` (from visualbasic reference) in an ASP.Net project using .Net 4.0 and that person keep forgetting removing it or commenting it out before checking it in to TFS.

Is there a way in visual studio or TFS to make a rule to make it not compile or not able to check-in with an active `msgbox`?

Comment: -1: You should do code reviews

Comment: While it is sometimes possible to find technical solutions to social problems, in general you do better to address the root cause.

Comment: @pantelif & AakashM, I tried both. I have no power over that person. So if I remove the ability of being able to use it. This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four options. My recommendation would be #3, using Gated Check-In to validate changes.

1. Find a non-technical way to **persuade them** not to do it (i.e. code reviews, etc)
2. Implement a **client-side checkin policy** (like the [code analysis checkin policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182075.aspx)). The positive of this approach is that you prevent the problem before the checkin occurs. The downside is that it's trivial to override a checkin policy and it's difficult to deploy them to client machines.
3. Implement a [**Gated Check-in Build Process**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx) with TFS Build 2010. If you didn't want to use Team Build to do the actual compilation of your project, you could implement [a minimal build process template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbar/archive/2010/04/29/what-is-the-most-minimal-build-process-template-possible.aspx) that just checks for bad things and rejects any checkins that contains them. The positive of this approach is that it's server-side and fairly easy to implement.
4. Implement a **server-side plugin**. Take a look at [Chapter 25 - Extending TFS from Professional Team Foundation Server](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Team-Foundation-Server-2010.productCd-0470943327.html) (*Disclaimer: I wrote the chapter*) and download the [Code Samples](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Team-Foundation-Server-2010.productCd-0470943327,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) for an example of how to do this. The downside of this approach is that it requires installing custom code on your server and its easy to get wrong.

Comment: I think we have tfs 2008, not really sure. I might look at #2 tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the code review and address the root cause, but you could investigate the usage of [custom code analysis rule](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have no *institutional* power over that person--which is tentative anyway. Can you engage them and come to an understanding?